# WAV file plays properly in WMP but not through the MediaElement?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I know this has been asked before but am still not able to play a wav file in wpf.

This is the code I am using.

```
 <MediaElement Name="mediaSound" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Source="Alarm10.wav"/>
```

and

```
  try
        {
            mediaSound.Play();
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
        }
```

No exception is thrown and the sound is not played.

Comment: Are you coding on a VM/through remote desktop?

Comment: no? why? will it matter?

Comment: Does that same `wav` file play in Windows Media Player properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is nothing wrong with the markup, I'm left to only believe that the location of `Alarm10.wav` **is not** in the `bin\*` directory in which the application is executing out of.

Another thing that needs to be evaluated is the volume level of the `MediaElement`, for example:

```
mediaSound.Volume = .75;
```

## EDIT

The OP confirmed it was the location of the WAV file that was the problem. When providing a path, it's relative to the `WorkingDirectory` of the application. During debugging this is the directory in which it's executing out of **(generally)**.

Comment: soundvolume is 100. Music file was in solution folder and not in debug. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @TanujWadhwa, that's what I thought might have been the issue. I'm glad I could be of assistance. I'll edit the answer to be clear it was the location of the file.